# How can I get a file list for a folder in my AWS bucket?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am working on AWS S3 using [Amazon S3 PHP Class](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/) (version 0.5.1-dev). I can get a list of all buckets using `$s3->listBuckets()`.

How do I get a list of all files in a folder?

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you're not talking about Amazon's PHP class for S3. You're talking about the [PHP class for *Amazon S3*](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/). (This is an unofficial, third-party class that is *not supported* by AWS.) If this is what you're using, you're looking for the [`S3::getBucket()`](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/S3.php#L411) method.

If you're looking for documentation on the *official* AWS SDK for PHP 1.6.2, you're looking for the [`AmazonS3::list_objects()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/list_objects) method.

If you're looking for documentation on the *official* AWS SDK for PHP 2.x, you're looking for the [`Aws\S3\S3Client::listObjects()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listObjects) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can list objects in a bucket by using the [`list_objects()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/list_objects) function.

Note that the version of the Amazon S3 SDK you're using is old. You may have better results using [version 2 of the AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/index.html).

Comment: He's actually not using the SDK 1.x. He's using an [unofficial, third-party S3 class](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/)... which is also old and outdated. Using the _official_ [AWS SDK for PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) will give you the best performance and results.

Comment: @Ryan Parman , Thanks for the reply. yes it is third party S3 class. It is used in Mediawiki extension LocalS3Repo2 (https://github.com/oborseth/LocalS3Repo2 )